# How to examine the structures in Windbg?

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to use dt command to see the values of the structure fields. But it doesn't work for some reason:

```js
dt ntkrnlmp!_SECURITY_SUBJECT_CONTEXT rdx
Cannot find specified field members.
```

Nevertheless, if I check if windbg knows the structure, it works just fine:

```js
dt ntkrnlmp!_SECURITY_SUBJECT_CONTEXT 
+0x000 ClientToken      : Ptr64 Void
+0x008 ImpersonationLevel : _SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
+0x010 PrimaryToken     : Ptr64 Void
+0x018 ProcessAuditId   : Ptr64 Void
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add @ before register name

dt foo!blah @bar or use

? @rdx and provide the physical value

dt foo!blah 0x13371337

Comment: It works! But what does @ mean?

Comment: @AntonKukoba It tells windbg that the supplied parameter is a register a not a structure field member. If you look at the [`dt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dt--display-type-) command help you can see that your command is ambiguous since the parameter can be understood either as an address or  a structure field name. See also [Register syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/register-syntax) in the official documentation.